# How to bring correct result from my data frame on R shiny?

Tags: r, dataframe, web, search, shiny

I want to have properly working search button on my shiny app which bring data from my data frame (table1).here is my data frame;

```
table1 = data_frame = ( 
Ciliopathy = c("Acrocallosal Syndrome" ,"Alström Syndrome" , "Ataxia- 
telangiectasia-like Disorder" ,"Ataxia-telangiectasia-like Disorder" , 
"Autosomal Dominant Polycystic Kidney Disease (ADPK)" ,"Autosomal 
Dominant Polycystic Kidney Disease (ADPK)" , "Autosomal Dominant 
Polycystic Kidney Disease (ADPK)", "Autosomal Dominant Polycystic Kidney 
Disease (ADPK)","Autosomal Dominant Polycystic Kidney Disease (ADPK)"),

OMIM.Phenotype.Number = 
c(200990,203800,604391,615919,173900,613095,613095,600666,600666),

Human.Gene.Name = 
c("KIF7","ALMS1","MRE11","PCNA","PKD1","PKD2","PKD2","GANAB","GANAB"))
```

But when i search a spesific word it doesnt bring desired result. I think problematic part is here;

```
generow = reactive({

table1 %>% filter (Human.Gene.Name == "a" )

})  

output$tablom <- renderTable({ 

generow()

})
```

but still i can't figure out how to solve, here is my full code;

```
 ui <- fluidPage(
tags$h1("Search Input"),
br(),
searchInput(
  inputId = "a", label = "Enter your text",
  placeholder = "A placeholder",
  btnSearch = icon("search"),
  btnReset = icon("remove"),
  width = "450px"
),
br(),
(outputId = "tablom"), tableOutput("tablom")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

generow = reactive({

 table1 %>% filter (Human.Gene.Name == "a" )

  })  

output$tablom <- renderTable({ 
  
  generow()

  })
 }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I need your suggestions

Comment: could you provide some data? like with dput(table1) ?

Comment: i have added first 10 rows of my data frame.

Comment: The dataframe code gives an error. You might be looking for `table1 %>% filter grepl("a",Human.Gene.Name))`

Answer (score 0):

Like I see in your sample Data your "Human Gene Name" is always a whole name.
You are filtering just for one letter with:

```
table1 %>% filter (Human.Gene.Name == "a" )
```

If you want to filter all genes, that includes an "a" you need another function

```
 grepl("a", table1$Human Gene Name)
```

Additionally your row is named "Human Gene Name", but you are using Human.Gene.Name in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response but i don't need true false response,i just want to search gene name and obtain ciliopathy and omim.phenotype.number of gene name.

Thats why i wrote
table1 %>% filter (Human.Gene.Name == "a" ) code, because my inputid="a" ( "a" considered as a searched gene name)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to your problem, I tryed it with:

```
Human.Gene.Name <- c("a", "ALMS1", "MRE11", "PCNA", "PKD1", "PKD2", "PKD2", "a","GANAB")
```

Here is the ui:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
          tags$h1("Search Input"),
          br(),
          searchInput(
                    inputId = "a", label = "Enter your text",
                    placeholder = "A placeholder",
                    btnSearch = icon("search"),
                    btnReset = icon("remove"),
                    width = "450px"
          ),
          br(),
          tableOutput(outputId = "tablom")
)
```

and the server:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
          
          input.word <- reactive({
                              input$a
                    })
        
          output$tablom <- renderTable({ 
                    
                    table1 %>% filter (Human.Gene.Name == as.character(input.word()) )%>%
                              select(OMIM.Phenotype.Number,Ciliopathy)
                    
          })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: better rename your inputId = "a" to "searchword" and then the reactive input to input$searchword.
Otherwise it leads to confusion if you name the variable "a" and also want to search for "a".